# Build Json with Objects in Objects(JS)

Tags: javascript, json

I want one json object but get multiple.

```js
let example = {
  test1: '',
  test2: '',
  oTest: {
    oTest1: '',
    oTest2: ''
  },
  ooTest: {
    ooTest1: '',
    ooTest2: null,
  }
};

let result = JSON.stringify({
  example,
  'oTest': example.oTest,
  'ooTest': example.ooTest
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(example));
```

My Result is that i get 3 seperate Json Objects(example,oTest,ooTest) but my goal is to have 1 Json Object "example" including oTest and ooTest. Also "example" dont show oTest and ooTest.

Goal:

```
{
  "test1": "",
  "test2": "",
  "oTest": {
    "oTest1": "",
    "oTest2": ""
  },
  "ooTest": {
    "ooTest1": "",
    "ooTest2": ""
  }
}
```

Comment: What output are you expecting exactly? `{test1:'', test2:'', oTest:''...}` or `{example: {test1:'' ...}}` or what exactly?

Comment: Your code is doing what `JSON.stringify(example)` **would already do for you**. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Please show the exact expected JSON you want as `result`.

Comment: is your goal ?? `{
  "test1": "",
  "test2": "",
  "oTest1": "",
  "oTest2": "",
  "ooTest1": "",
  "ooTest2": null
}` coz it seems your expected result is same as your original object

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing doesn't make sense at all. Your expected result is returned by just passing `example` to JSON.stringify

```
JSON.stringify(example);
```

Comment: This dont work because it ignores oTest and ooTest and only shows "test1" and "test2"

Answer (score -1):

```
JSON.stringify(Object.assign(example,{'oTest': example.oTest},{'ooTest': example.ooTest})
```

This is merge all the 3 object in one, and return back a stringified object.

Comment: Explain what your answer does.

Comment: This one did help thanks :) Sorry for confusing im new to programming

Comment: This does exactly the same that `JSON.stringify(example)` does.